# Uploading war file hangs on starting in SAP Cloud Platform Neo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sap-business-technology-platform

based on this guide here:

https://medium.com/pacroy/running-spring-boot-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-ceede6d65106

I have downloaded the code here and built it as a war file.

https://github.com/pacroy/spring-boot-helloscp

I have then deployed the war to my neo environment. After starting the application it then allocates the environment but hangs indefinitely on the starting indicator.

The first log file created contains a large stack trace:

```
FILE_TYPE:DAAA96DE-B0FB-4c6e-AF7B-A445F5BF9BE2
FILE_ID:1528757579497
ENCODING:[UTF8|NWCJS:ASCII]
RECORD_SEPARATOR:124
COLUMN_SEPARATOR:35
ESC_CHARACTER:92
COLUMNS:Time|Severity|Logger|Thread|n/a|Text|
SEVERITY_MAP:FINEST|Information|FINER|Information|FINE|Information|CONFIG|Information|DEBUG|Information|PATH|Information|INFO|Information|WARNING|Warning|ERROR|Error|SEVERE|Error|FATAL|Error
HEADER_END

2018 06 11 22:53:11#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##22:53:11.308 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.|
2018 06 11 22:53:11#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##22:53:11.316 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/bin/logback-classic.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]|
2018 06 11 22:53:11#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##22:53:11.316 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/helloscp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]|
2018 06 11 22:53:11#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##22:53:11.317 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.|
2018 06 11 22:53:11#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##22:53:11.668 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14##Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.StackOverflowError|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:169)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:103)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1154)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:931)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:180)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:103)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1154)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:931)|
```

The last 9 line are then repeated until the bottom:

```
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:180)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:103)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1154)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:931)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at sun.rmi.runtime.Log$LoggerLog.log(Log.java:229)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPConnection.close(TCPConnection.java:219)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:597)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)|
2018 06 11 22:53:13#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-14## at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)|
```

The top part repeated many times before getting to the last part.

The garbage collection log looks like this:

```
2018-06-11T22:53:06.936+0000: 6.091: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) 2018-06-11T22:53:06.936+0000: 6.091: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) 6.091: [ParNew: 136862K->13193K(189952K), 0.0774287 secs] 136862K->13193K(1234432K), 0.0774859 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs] 
[1 CMS-initial-mark: 0K(1044480K)] 13193K(1234432K), 0.0940998 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:07.044+0000: 6.199: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2018-06-11T22:53:07.055+0000: 6.210: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.011/0.011 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:07.083+0000: 6.237: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2018-06-11T22:53:07.085+0000: 6.239: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:07.085+0000: 6.239: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2018-06-11T22:53:09.101+0000: 8.255: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.634/2.016 secs] [Times: user=1.79 sys=0.06, real=2.02 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:09.101+0000: 8.255: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 100172 K (189952 K)]8.256: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0467687 secs]8.302: [weak refs processing, 0.0000982 secs]8.302: [class unloading, 0.0034457 secs]8.306: [scrub symbol table, 0.0043437 secs]8.310: [scrub string table, 0.0008146 secs][1 CMS-remark: 0K(1044480K)] 100172K(1234432K), 0.0563585 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:09.165+0000: 8.319: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2018-06-11T22:53:09.165+0000: 8.319: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:09.165+0000: 8.319: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2018-06-11T22:53:09.190+0000: 8.345: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.022/0.025 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:09.923+0000: 9.077: [GC (Allocation Failure) 9.077: [ParNew: 184201K->8052K(189952K), 0.0768536 secs] 184201K->19261K(1234432K), 0.0769170 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.01, real=0.08 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:10.781+0000: 9.935: [GC (Allocation Failure) 9.935: [ParNew: 179060K->11585K(189952K), 0.0294688 secs] 190269K->22794K(1234432K), 0.0295479 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:53:13.361+0000: 12.516: [GC (Allocation Failure) 12.516: [ParNew: 182593K->4682K(189952K), 0.0324057 secs] 193802K->19258K(1234432K), 0.0324760 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2018-06-11T22:55:11.521+0000: 130.675: [GC (Allocation Failure) 130.675: [ParNew: 175690K->3079K(189952K), 0.0497712 secs] 190266K->17654K(1234432K), 0.0498596 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
```

The another log file looks like this:

```
FILE_TYPE:DAAA96DE-B0FB-4c6e-AF7B-A445F5BF9BE2
FILE_ID:1528758813082
ENCODING:[UTF8|NWCJS:ASCII]
RECORD_SEPARATOR:124
COLUMN_SEPARATOR:35
ESC_CHARACTER:92
COLUMNS:Time|Severity|Logger|Thread|n/a|Text|
SEVERITY_MAP:FINEST|Information|FINER|Information|FINE|Information|CONFIG|Information|DEBUG|Information|PATH|Information|INFO|Information|WARNING|Warning|ERROR|Error|SEVERE|Error|FATAL|Error
HEADER_END

2018 06 11 23:13:42#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##23:13:42.283 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.|
2018 06 11 23:13:42#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##23:13:42.289 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/bin/logback-classic.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]|
2018 06 11 23:13:42#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##23:13:42.290 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/helloscp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]|
2018 06 11 23:13:42#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##23:13:42.291 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.|
2018 06 11 23:13:42#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-13##23:13:42.553 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder
```

And the last log file that I can see looks like this:

```
---
VM version: Nov 29 2017 10:19:58 - 81_REL - optU - linux amd64 - 6 - bas2:297759 (mixed mode)

Time:2018-06-1122:53:13
Pid: 16411
Hostname: vsa4371811
current dir: /usr/sap/ljs
---
   :    [140545891444480]   22:53:13 ***ERROR (:0): StackOverflowError
   :    [140545929889536]   22:53:13 ***ERROR (:0): StackOverflowError
   :    [140545891444480]   22:53:13 ***ERROR (:0): StackOverflowError
   :    [140545929889536]   22:53:13 ***ERROR (:0): StackOverflowError
   :    [140545891444480]   22:53:13 ***ERROR (:0): StackOverflowError
```

I have tried this with another spring boot application (The one I am actually trying to get to run) with identical results. I have also tried with a Lite compute unit and a Pro compute unit. This is both set to an apache tomcat 8 server.

So I am wondering what could be wrong here?

Comment: [edit] your question and include the COMPLETE stack trace, including all "Caused by" sections.

Comment: @JimGarrison From the first log file? Stackoverflow won't let me include the entire log file so I included only the unique lines.